# Change chalk color in RISE chalkboard

Tags: jupyter-notebook, reveal.js, rise

I am using RISE in a jupyter notebook with python and enjoying the chalkboard feature. But when using a dark theme the default blue color is hard to see.

I have been trying many (even weird) things and I only could change the color to black (that is even worse with dark themes) editing the Notebook Metadata this way:

```
  "rise": {
    "chalkboard": {
      "color": "rgb(250, 250, 250)"
    },
    "enable_chalkboard": true
  }
```

It does not matter what numbers you choose inside the `rgb()`, it always produces black. It behaves like reveal.js is trying to change the color, but looks like it is having issues while parsing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RISE is using [v1.0.0](https://github.com/damianavila/RISE/blob/5.6.1/package.json#L12) of [reveal.js-chalkboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reveal.js-chalkboard)

[This version](https://github.com/rajgoel/reveal.js-plugins/commit/94ab4304095429223803c94b3fdc518159ea2ffd#diff-edafa86598bffa74915dd55d299fcd5bL103) has `color` option informed as an array of colors where the first color gives pen color and the second color gives board drawings color.

For example,

```
  "rise": {
    "chalkboard": {
      "color": ["rgb(250, 250, 250)", "rgb(250, 250, 250)"]
    },
    "enable_chalkboard": true
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible to choose and switch different colors?